# why angular gives function not a function, undefined error (Works fine when I change the CDN version)

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm new to MEAN stack technology and building a testing app. I'm using angulrjs as follow.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <title>contact lists app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<h1>Contact List app</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function AppCtrl(){
  console.log("testing");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

while this running in the server, I looked for console in the browser.then it show following error

[image]

and the link description was

[image]

before I add this, angular works fine and didn't show any error.hope your help with this.thanx

**NOTE : I tried by adding a custom js file in different folder, it also didn't work**

**NOTE:I'M USING GOOGLE CDN TO WORK WITH ANGULAR.IN HERE I HAVE USED LATEST VERSION, WHICH THEY ARE PROVIDING.BUT IF I USED PREVIOUS VERSION LIKE :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**THEN IT WORKS FINE.**

Comment: You should really read the angularjs documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide). There are also alot of examples. In this case you need to create a Controller (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller). There are working examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to instantiate the module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

Then you have to instantiate your controller:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

You can learn more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

Comment: yep, it's working fine  in this way.thank you very much. but it works fine if I change the `version` of `CDN`. is there an issue with the version.